# Disable json root element in embedded objects on ActiveResource query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, activeresource

I got problem with unnecessary root element in embedded json object.
Here is the cleaned sources:

User model:

```
class User < ActiveResource::Base
      self.format = :json
      self.element_name = "user"
      #...
end
```

Controller's action 'new'

```
def new
 @user = User.build
 @user.id = nil
end
```

User.build gives me next json:

```
{
  "id":0,
  "user_name":null,
  "credit_card":
    {"number":null}
}
```

Controller's action 'create'

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    @user.save
end
```

View '_form.html.erb'

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :user_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :user_name %>

        <%= f.fields_for @user.credit_card do |cc_f| %>
            <%= cc_f.label :number %>
            <%= cc_f.text_field :number %>
        <% end %>
<% end %>
```

When I'm saving user app send next json:

```
{
 "user"=>
   {"credit_card"=>
     {"credit_card"=>
       {"number"=>"xxxxyyyyzzzzaaaa"}
     }, 
   "user_name"=>"test"
    }, 
 "api_client_key"=>"top_secret"
}
```

Problem is in duplication of credit_card keys. How can i solve it?

---

Final solution:

```
class User < ActiveResource::Base
      self.include_root_in_json = false
      self.format = :json
      self.element_name = "user"

      def to_json(options = {})
          {
             self.class.element_name => self.attributes
          }.to_json(options)
      end
# ...
end
```

thanks to Oliver Barnes

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
ActiveResource::Base.include_root_in_json = false
```

If you need to keep the top root and just remove the associated credit card object's root, then you might need to customize the json output with #to_json, like this:

```
def to_json(options = {})
  { "user"=>
      {"credit_card"=>
        {"number"=> self.credit_card.number }
       }, 
        "user_name"=> self.user_name
   }.to_json(options)
end
```

Comment: why ActiveRecord if questrion is about ActiveResource ?

Comment: ActiveResource has the same parameter. But it removes "user" element too.

Comment: I need the following request:  
`{
"user"=>{"user_name"=>"test", "credit_card"=>{"number"=>"..."}},
"api_client_key"=>"top_secret"
}`

But i get

`{
"user_name"=>"test",
"credit_card"=>{"number"=>"..."},
"api_client_key"=>"top_secret"
}`

Comment: @Fivell late night answer, fixing it

Comment: @mind.debug, if you need the top level root but not the associated roots, you might need to customize the output with as_json. adding this to the answer now

Comment: looks like ActiveResource doesn't have AR's #as_json, only #to_json

Comment: everything work's fine. i add the final solution to the end of question

Comment: include_root_in_json = false saved me! Thank you very much :)